For an analytic function $f$ in a domain $D$, if $\log|f|$ is harmonic in a neighborhood of $\partial D$ then $f\in C(\bar D)$.
I have stuck in one place while reading a paper. If $\phi$ is an analytic function on $D$, where $D$ is bounded multiple connected domains in $\mathbb{C}$. Now given that $\log\lvert \phi\rvert$ is harmonic in the neighborhood of $\partial D$ then the author claim $\phi$ can be extended continuously on $\bar{D}$. My question is how to prove $\phi$ has continuous extension? I can only conclude that $\lvert \phi\rvert$ is continous on $\bar D$, but nothing about the continuity of $\phi$ on $\bar D$.

The hypothesis implies $\phi$ doesn't vanish on a neighborhood of the boundary so there is a harmonic conjugate to $\log |\phi|$ in the neighborhood of any boundary point, hence an analytic extension of $\log \phi$ so of $\phi$ hence in particular $\phi$ extends continuously to the boundary - note that in general you may not be able to patch together all local analytic extensions of $\phi$ beyond the boundary
